# JBPM/Spring Boot/Gradle configuration problem

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, jbpm

Attempting to get jBPM running in a spring boot application, using gradle.

When starting I get

Logger=o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper, - Table "TASK" not found (this database is empty); SQL statement:
select taskimpl0_.id as col_0_0_, deadlineim1_.id as col_1_0_, deadlineim1_.deadline_date as col_2_0_ from Task taskimpl0_ cross join Deadline deadlineim1_ where taskimpl0_.archived=0 and (deadlineim1_.id in (select startdeadl2_.id from Deadline startdeadl2_ where taskimpl0_.id=startdeadl2_.Deadlines_StartDeadLine_Id)) and deadlineim1_.escalated=0 order by deadlineim1_.deadline_date [42104-214]

So, it appears the H2 database isn't getting initialized with the correct tables. Do I need to provide a persistence.xml file? Should one already be in the class path?

Using this basic configuration found at: https://github.com/tsurdilo/jbpm-business-apps-gradle

I am using KIE version 7.59.0.Final (but have tried a few others).
I am not providing any H2 configuration details as I have read this configuration is provided out-of-the-box, so my configuration is pretty minimal.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the solution. Just needed to follow the instructions at https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_process_automation_manager/7.5/html/installing_and_configuring_red_hat_process_automation_manager_on_red_hat_jboss_web_server/process_server_zip_file_installation_and_configuration#jws-jdbc-config_install-on-jws to download the DDL scripts.

- Downloaded the "add ons" zip file
- Extracted the h2 scripts
- Copied them into the resources file
- Modified the application.yml to add the spring.sql.init.data-locations property pointing to the various script files

While running found that there are many sequences missing including:
SESSIONINFO_ID_SEQ
PROCESS_INSTANCE_INFO_ID_SEQ
CORRELATION_KEY_ID_SEQ
CORRELATION_PROP_ID_SEQ
VAR_INST_LOG_ID_SEQ
PROC_INST_LOG_ID_SEQ
NODE_INST_LOG_ID_SEQ
EXEC_ERROR_INFO_ID_SEQ

Added them to an additional sql file. Seems to work